# ruby multiple where operator with jsonb column and non jsonb columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, where-clause, jsonb

I am trying to make a query that includes a jsonb column and 2 non jsonb columns.

Multiple attempts to combine them have failed but 1 nearly worked when I only used 1 other non jsonb column. I have a channel model with an 'options' store and several attributes within.

If i separate the queries they work just fine but combined they retrieve an empty array. I have made sure that if the queries did work, there is definitely data for them to return.

Non jsonb columns - works

```
Channel.where("platform_id = ? AND updated_at < ?",2,7.days.ago)
```

jsonb column - works

```
Channel.where("options @> ?", {valid_account: true}.to_json)
```

combined where operator - returns empty []

```
Channel.where("platform_id = ? AND updated_at < ?",2,7.days.ago).where("options @> ?", {valid_account: true}.to_json)
```

1 where operator with combined query - again, returns empty []

```
Channel.where("options = ? AND platform_id = ? AND updated_at < ?", {"valid_account" => true}.to_json, 2, 7.days.ago)
```

Am at a loss now and not sure how to get this all into one query... or if it's even possible.

Again... there are definitely channels that should return with the given queries above

TIA

**UPDATE**

Managed to get the query to work. tried nearly every combination but missed one critical one.

```
Channel.where("options @> ? AND platform_id = ? AND updated_at > ?", {valid_account: true}.to_json, 2, 7.days.ago)
```

this worked. For some reason I had used the '>@' in a separate method but not combined it for this. All working now. Thanks for the support

Comment: Please run this command and share the result: Channel.where("options = ? AND platform_id = ? AND updated_at < ?", {"valid_account" => true}.to_json, 2, 7.days.ago).to_sql

Comment: Do the 1st and 2nd query have elements in common?

Comment: or write result for `Channel.where("platform_id = ? AND updated_at < ?",2,7.days.ago).pluck(:id)` and `Channel.where("options @> ?", {valid_account: true}.to_json).pluck(:id)`. This will enable us to see if there are some common records which should be returned as a result of combined query.

Comment: @Fernand - "SELECT \"channels\".* FROM \"channels\" WHERE (options = '{\"valid_account\":true}' AND platform_id = 2 AND updated_at < '2020-01-09 15:40:59.835528')"

Comment: Go ahead and create an answer for your question below and accept it. This will let others know you don’t need help, and it’ll direct other people with similar problems to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to include '>@' in the query for the jsonb column

```
Channel.where("options @> ? AND platform_id = ? AND updated_at > ?", {valid_account: true}.to_json, 2, 7.days.ago
```